# Calculating average number of boxes needed to obtain materials to make blanket

Tags: probability, average

Let's say that I am gifted several boxes, each containing 1 single material inside of them.

The chance of obtaining all possible Materials (A-E) are as follows:

- Material A 5%
- Material B 30%
- Material C 40%
- Material D 15%
- Material E 10%

I need the following materials to make the blanket:

- Material A x4
- Material B x1
- Material C x1
- Material D x0
- Material E x2

The question to answer is, what is the average number of boxes needing to be opened in order to have enough materials to make the blanket??

If anyone knows how to go about tackling this some help would be excellent!
I initially tried tackling this problem by (material type needed/material % drop) then added the sum of all these up, but that was clearly the wrong way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Often, and it is the case here, there is one material that is the rare one.  By the time you get enough of that one, you are (almost) guaranteed to have enough of everything else.  Here it is A that is rare.  You only get it one time in $20$ and you need $4$, so you should expect to need $80$ boxes.  By that time you expect $8$ pieces of E and only need $2$, so the chance you don't have your $2$ is pretty small.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Ross! I did have one question for you. If I wanted to apply this to a larger scale say 100 chests. Is the correct solution to find the average for each chest to calculate which material will take the longest individually to collect and by that time the player should have collected all the other materials??

Comment: That is an approximation which will be quite accurate, but low, when one material takes much longer than all the others.  At the other end, if you have $100$ materials and need one of each we have the [coupon collector problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector's_problem), for which the expected time is $519$ boxes.  Although each one should be obtained with an expected time of $100$, one or more will lag badly.

Comment: In your original example, we can compute the chance that after $80$ boxes you are still short of E, the next most likely to be a problem.  The chance you have none of E is $.9^{80} \approx 0.0002$.  The chance you only have one is $80\cdot 0.1 \cdot .9^{79}$ or about $9$ times higher, so there is only one chance in $500$ you don't have enough of E after $80$ boxes.